# paypal express integration what return url to use?

Tags: php, paypal

i used the paypal integration wizard for php and downloaded all the files that it showed me.
i setup the api information and all is good there.
i load the page and it has the paypal buy now button i pressed it and i get redirect to paypal to login.
i logged in with a sandbox login and verified the data shown on the next page and pressed continue.
then i get redirected to the return url that i had specied.

my question is what return url am i supposed to use? the return url i specified has both BuyerID and token. how do i use these parameters to charge the client the final cost?

i am really confused sorry.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return_url is where paypal redirects the user **after** successful payment.

how it works is customer buys a product and goes through the process then is redirected back to your site
then the paypal IPN will POST back to your script with parameters like (item_name,item_number,payment_status,mc_gross,mc_currency,txn_id,receiver_email,payer_email) then your script calls back to paypal with a command cmd=_notify-validate then if result is VERIFIED updates the db. i not 100% sure im right but there a many IPN solutions out there. theres an example code here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

**Note: To activate Instant Payment Notification, you will need to enter the URL at which you would like to receive the notification posts from your PayPal Profile.**

Comment: what can i use the token and buyerid for? and how can i check if the transaction was successful. i just logged in and i saw the transactions funny thing is though i got no alert that it was done.

Comment: i tried to make a new transaction and nothing is going through when i click the checkout button i get redirected to login into paypal and i see this page http://i56.tinypic.com/5ozj89.png  when i click continue i go to the return page. i feel like im doing something wrong. transactions arent going through

Comment: im not sure what script your using, note the paypal callback cant get through your firewall if your testing locally

Comment: i'm testing it on a server. here is my script its very short it only contains the paypal files. http://69.231.195.173:8888/paypal.zip  i am using the paypal integration wizard (https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php) its the page where paypal helps you put together all the files and code needed to make it work. can you please help me out with what i provided. :) i thank you alot

Comment: ok had a quick look n that script doesn't support IPN. what it does is hold all the results from the paypal payment into a $_SESSION variable called $_SESSION['nvpReqArray'], on the return.php page type out echo"<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);echo"</pre>"; and your see all the info once your sent back there, how it would normally work is on the return page you update the db with payment received ect depending if the results are in that session var

Comment: a good script i use for IPN on a single product can be found here http://www.ngcoders.com/php/selling-digital-goods-with-paypal-ipn-and-php